# Is there a way to temporarily disable segfault messages in dmesg?

Tags: linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, dmesg

Linux kernel keeps logging segfaults in ring buffer.

```
a.out[25415]: segfault at 8049604 ip 08049604 sp bf88e3fc error 15 in a.out[8049000+1000]
```

Is there a way to temporarily disable it?  My usecase is that I'm running a testsuite that does all sorts of crazy things and I don't want to see segfaults in `dmesg` from that time period.  `dmesg -c` is not an option because the test framework I'm forced to use is analyzing dmesg output and I cannot just clear it in the middle.

I was going through `sysctl -a` output if there's some kernel parameter, but I don't see anything that appears to be useful. `kernel.print-fatal-signals` looked promising but it's just for showing more detailed info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, I eventually found it.  It's called `debug.exception-trace`.

`sysctl -w debug.exception-trace=0` or `echo 0 > /proc/sys/debug/exception-trace` will turn it off.

```
# dmesg -c
# dmesg
# echo 'main;' | gcc -xc - && ./a.out
<stdin>:1:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
Segmentation fault
# dmesg
[  539.421736] a.out[1875]: segfault at 600874 ip 0000000000600874 sp 00007ffed85e7018 error 15 in a.out[600000+1000]
# sysctl debug.exception-trace
debug.exception-trace = 1 
# ./a.out 
Segmentation fault
# dmesg
[  539.421736] a.out[1875]: segfault at 600874 ip 0000000000600874 sp 00007ffed85e7018 error 15 in a.out[600000+1000]
[  584.492171] a.out[1878]: segfault at 600874 ip 0000000000600874 sp 00007ffc6b0d2358 error 15 in a.out[600000+1000]
# sysctl -w debug.exception-trace=0
debug.exception-trace = 0 
# ./a.out 
Segmentation fault
# dmesg
[  539.421736] a.out[1875]: segfault at 600874 ip 0000000000600874 sp 00007ffed85e7018 error 15 in a.out[600000+1000]
[  584.492171] a.out[1878]: segfault at 600874 ip 0000000000600874 sp 00007ffc6b0d2358 error 15 in a.out[600000+1000]
```

The last segfault is not logged.

Comment: спасибо, друг :)  it's `CONFIG_SYSCTL_EXCEPTION_TRACE`, just in case